# How to use setOptions method of select field with a store

Tags: sencha-touch

I can use the setOptions method to successfully specify the options of a select field as follows:

```
setOptions(
[   {text: 'First Option',  value: 'first'},
{text: 'Second Option', value: 'second'},
{text: 'Third Option',  value: 'third'}
])
```

However, I would instead like setOptions to work with a loaded data store rather than hard coding the text/value array like above.

The store has one item type in it 'vehicle' and the json response from the server which loads it is of the form {'vehicle' :'mercedes'}, {'vehicle' 'jaguar'} (ignore if I have the json syntax wrong, am typing this from memory. And finally, I would be fine with having the value field being the same as the text field for setOptions.

However, I am stumped how to accomplish this. Many thanks to anyone who can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
{         id: 'theSelect',
        name: 'vechicleSelect',
       xtype: 'selectfield',
       store: storeObejct,
displayField: 'vehicle',
  valueField: 'vehicle'
}
```

Read the whole API here [Sencha Touch selectfield](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/docs/?class=Ext.form.Select)

Comment: Hi llya thanks for the reply. That works but I would like to accomplish this using the setOptions method or similar - this is because I have a placeholder on the selectfield with no values in it and I am then updating the fields later on with setOptions as above. (You may remember actually that you helped me with that a few days ago)

Comment: Do you have to use the store? If not you can pass the JSON string " {'vehicle' :'mercedes'}, {'vehicle' 'jaguar'} " in the `setOptions` method.

Comment: If you have to use the store then set it up as in my answer and then use this to set the placeholder text: 
`Ext.getCmp('theSelect').el.dom.firstChild.firstChild.placeholder = 'Placeholder value';`

Answer (score 1):

You could cycle through the store and push the data into an array then use the array as the argument for setOptions.

Answer (score 1):

To add to warmachine's answer...
In your view:

```
                {
                    xtype: 'selectfield',
                    id: 'NameId',
                    label: 'Name',
                    labelWrap: true,
                    placeHolder: 'name'
                },
```

Controller or initialize function in your view:

```
initialize: function(){

    var me = this;
    me.callParent(arguments);

    var sto= Ext.getStore('Persons');
    sto.load();

    var options = [];

    sto.each(function(record){
        options.push({
            value: record.get('displayname'),
            text: record.get('displayname')
        });
    });

    var box = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#NameId')[0];

    box.setOptions(options);
},
```